# Pass python script directly to python -m timeit

Tags: python, command-line, runtime, timeit

According to the offical documentation of [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit-command-line-interface), I can time simple python snippets using the command line interface as follows

```
python3 -m timeit -n 5 "'-'.join(str(n) for n in range(100))"
```

I can also execute a python3 script named **script.py** by running

```
python3 script.py
```

Because of this I assumed I would be able to do something like this

```
python3 -m timeit -n 5 script.py
```

but this does not work.

**script.py** is not a module so some suggestions along the lines of

```
python3 -m timeit -n 5 -s 'import script(.py)'
```

do not work either.

I am a bit out of ideas how I could accomplish my goal, thus my question is

#### Is there any good option to measure the run time of an python script using `python3 -m timeit` directly from the command line?

Also, I do not want to do things like:

- using the time command in linux
- import the timeit module in my python script itself

Already thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: The module `timeit` is designed for timing code in the form of strings, not files. Why do you want to use it for something that it is not designed for? Why do you try to avoid using the command `time`, perfectly suitable for this job?

Comment: With `timeit` I can easly specify the number of times to execute the statement, which is not possible with time as far as I have seen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```py
python3 -m timeit -r 1 -s "import subprocess" "subprocess.run(['python3', 'script_name.py'])"
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach that comes to my mind is to execute script.py using `os.system("python3 script.py"))`. So:

```
python3 -m timeit -n 5 -s "import os; os.system('python3 script.py')"
```